# Best norm of $A$ in order to approximate $x^TAx$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ a positive definite matrix and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am intetested in $x^TAx$.

However, I do not have $A$ explicitly and I need to approximate it by $\widetilde{A}$, the best rank-$k$ of $A$ in some norm (for some given $k$). In what norm is it best to approximate $A$ (i.e., to minimize $\lVert  A - \widetilde{A}\rVert_?$) in order to minimize $|x^TAx - x^T\widetilde{A}x|$?

Comment: Some details are missing. What constraints are there on $\tilde{A}$? Do you want to find one $\tilde{A}$ for one $x$, or should one $\tilde{A}$ be a good match for all $x$? How do you make a trade-off for different $x$?

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. $\tilde{A}$ is the "best approximation" of $A$ in some norm. I wish to find an $\tilde{A}$ to be a good match for all $x$. I haven't thought about your last question. Are you familiar with some work regarding that problem?

Comment: If $\widetilde{A}$ is not constrained, any norm will do, because $\|A-\widetilde{A}\|$ is minimised only when $\widetilde{A}=A$.

Comment: @user1551 you are right, I forgot to add the rank constraint. I revised the question.

Comment: Is $x$ fixed, or are you trying to select a norm to get a good approximation of $x^T A x$ on a domain (like the unit sphere)? And what do you know about $A$ besides that it is positive definite, if anything? (Presumably if $x$ is not fixed, you want to choose a norm which points strongly towards the eigenvectors of $A$ with large eigenvalues, but if you don't know anything about what those are then that's a problem.)